# Dataset of explosion audio (or video with audio) recordings

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, audio, video

Does anyone know if there is an audio dataset containing explosions? I'm trying to train a neural network in recognizing explosions sounds.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is probably what you are looking for [Google-audiose-explosion](https://research.google.com/audioset/dataset/explosion.html). Also you might find other audio datasets that might fit into your search criteria under https://research.google.com/audioset/dataset/index.html by filtering using words like "bang" or "boom" etc.

I just came across this [freesound-explosions-db](https://annotator.freesound.org/fsd/explore/%252Fm%252F014zdl/) , so maybe it can be a good alternative to the google dataset.

Comment: I should've mentioned that but I already checked the google dataset - it's very "polluted" with various artificial sound effects which I don't think translate to a good training dataset for real life applications.

Comment: @Felczer please edit your question accordingly